# perl one-liner to split files every given word

Tags: perl, file, split

Once again making some questions. I have a file of the form:

```
>seq1
123 234 56
167 332 22
23 456 098
>seq2
123 234 56
167 332 22
23 456 098
```

I want to have a file saving each >seq#, like this:

File 1:

```
>seq1
123 234 56
167 332 22
23 456 098
```

File 2:

```
>seq2
123 234 56
167 332 22
23 456 098
```

I could use a perl script but was wondering how this could be done using a perl one-liner, just for the sake of increasing my perl knowledge.

Thanks!!

Comment: You do know that there are lots of modules for biology stuff, right? http://search.cpan.org

Comment: Yes I know, but I still want to try a one-liner to know. These are not fasta files, but actual number tables.

Comment: Unless there's a module that provides support for that, you're likely to find it too big to be a sane one-liner.  I'm 99% sure I'd use a dozen or so lines for the task.  You might be able to cheat slightly by using the `>seq1` lines as an argument to the two-argument form of `open`, but that's only a minor point.  A lot depends on how robust you want the code to be.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually, if you use `$/ = "\n>"` you could probably do it pretty easily. `perl -lwe'$/="\n>"; while (<>) { open my $fh, ">", "file" . ++$i . ".txt" or die $!; print $fh $_; }'  seq.txt`

Comment: Hmmm... no, that doesn't quite work, I see now, well, perhaps it can be tweaked.

Comment: I love perl oneliners, because many times save my time. But will never use `perl -nle 'print if m/some/'` because i have a better tool called `grep`. So, in your case - wondering why do you don't use the `csplit`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather minimal script that does the job:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $fh = *STDOUT;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    if (m/^>/)
    {
        close $fh;
        open $fh, $_ or die "Failed to open $_";
    }
    print $fh "$_\n";
}
```

The `my $fh = *STDOUT;` line means that if there is stuff before the first `>file` line, it is echoed to standard output.

With that as a basis, you can decide to flatten it to one line, ignoring errors, closing open files, strictures and readability:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){chomp;open$f,$_ if(m/^>/);print$f "$_\n";}'
```

I couldn't possibly recommend that, though.  (Yes, both the blanks are necessary.)

Comment: `perl -e'while(<>) { ... }` aka `perl -ne'...'`. `chomp; ... print "$_\n"` aka `perl -l`. `perl -nle'if (/^>/) { open $fh, $_; } print $fh $_; '`

Comment: It might even be possible to rely on open failing silently and harmlessly by doing this: `perl -ple'open STDOUT, $_'`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. Its formatted exactly the same way as your one-liner. Even so, I added it in an answer to make room for explanations. It's quite an odd little feature I found, almost worthy of some obfuscation award.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, very good exercise indeed and thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17736379/725418), I came up with something that is odd enough to post a new answer for. I would like to add that this should be considered an exercise example (perhaps obfuscation), and not in any way proper code. Full credit for the solution goes to Jonathan. Also, this is a dangerous solution, as explained at the bottom.

```
perl -ple 'open STDOUT, $_' yourfile.txt
```

This relies on the lines that begin with `>seq1` to be used with the old 2-argument `open`, which [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) discovered. E.g. `open $fh, ">seq1"` will create (overwrite) and open the file `seq1` for writing.

At the same time, any line that does not have a valid "mode" symbol -- `<`, `>`, `|` etc. -- will be opened for reading by default, and if we gamble on the fact that no files with the names `123 234 56` etc exist in that directory, we can rely on our `open` to fail silently and maintain the previously opened `STDOUT` file handle.

By using the `-l` option, we do not need to `chomp` `$_` so that the `open` does not fail, nor do we need to add a newline to the print. At the same time, the `-p` option will take care of creating the `while` loop and do the printing.

Because the print by default goes to `STDOUT`, all we need to do is reopen the `STDOUT` file handle, and the content of the input file takes care of the rest.

The full code of this one-liner with comments to denote which parts come from which switch:

```
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }    # -l, gives newlines to print
while (<>) {                       # -p 
    chomp $_;                      # -l
    open STDOUT, $_;               # our code
}
continue {
    print STDOUT $_;               # -p
}
```

**Note:** This code will release the full power of the `open` command, which is dangerous as it would, in this case, allow arbitrary commands to be executed on your file system. This is a side effect of allowing the use of 2-argument open.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about -l option and how it saves us a chomp. Thanks!